# How to pass JSONObject to JavaScript function during on change event in HTML

Tags: java, javascript, html, json, jakarta-ee

I am populating a JSONObject from backend Java and setting it to variable in JSP.

I need to pass the variable to JavaScript function during `onchange` event.

I am getting syntax error during `onchange` due to quotes present in the JSONObject.

If I populate as a Map in backend java and I can able to set it to a variable in JSP and pass to JavaScript function successfully.

My question?

1. Shall we pass the JSONObject in onchange event as mentioned above. If yes what could be the syntax.

I used `onchange="getCountries('${countryJSON}')"` which is not working.

2. If we escape the quotes in JSONObject, is it possible to parse the JSONObject in JavaScript function.
3. Any alternative approach for this issue.